# How to perform footer summary and Group Summary in AspxGridView using dynamic binding?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

I made a code to show the records using AspxGridView. Now I want to show the sum(Column_Name), count(Column_Name) for Footer and Grouping.

This is my code:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" >
                    <SettingsPager PageSize="50">
                    </SettingsPager>
                    <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFooter="True" ShowGroupFooter="VisibleIfExpanded" />
                    <SettingsCommandButton>
                        <ShowAdaptiveDetailButton ButtonType="Image"></ShowAdaptiveDetailButton>

                        <HideAdaptiveDetailButton ButtonType="Image"></HideAdaptiveDetailButton>
                    </SettingsCommandButton>
                    <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="False" AllowInsert="False" />
                    <SettingsSearchPanel Visible="True" />
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ASPxGridView1.Visible = true;
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQMatajerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            whereQuery = getWhereQuery();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                string querysss = "select   "+txtSelectedColumn.Text+ @"
                            FROM        [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction] as transactions
                            RIGHT JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] as transactionsEntry
                            ON transactions.TransactionNumber=transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber 
                            INNER JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] as items
                            ON transactionsEntry.ItemID=items.ID
                            INNER JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Supplier] as suppliers
                            ON items.SupplierID=suppliers.ID
                            LEFT JOIN [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Department] as departments
                            ON departments.ID=items.DepartmentID
                            LEFT JOIN [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Category] as categories
                            ON categories.ID=items.CategoryID
                            where  " + txtQuery.Text;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = querysss;
                con.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                sda.Fill(ds);

                ASPxGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                ASPxGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

You can notice that my sql query statement. In that user only decide which column they want to display. If they select Price column_name in select statement. It has to display sum(price) in footer for over all records and for grouping as well if user do grouping

Comment: Perhaps start using LINQ to Entities? And Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a summary item in c# code and change the field name in every postback. e.g. for footer summary

```
ASPxSummaryItem gs = new ASPxSummaryItem();
gs.FieldName = txtSelectedColumn.Text;
gs.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum;
this.ASPxGridView1.TotalSummary.Add(gs);
```

If the field name doesn't change, you can delete old summaries and add a new one every time at the desired column. You could also do the same for every group summary. You could also check these out https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_GroupSummarytopic and https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_TotalSummarytopic